# How identify source from google assistant on dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, sonos

i have 2 sonos speaker. I have done an application on dialogflow where i can say "play muse" to listen my mp3 on them. The sentence is send to a php webserver (with a webhook) and the sound is send to the sonos with the api. But, the only solution i have found to identify the source, is to add:
"play muse on the kitchen", or "play muse on the bedroom".
I dont know how to identify the source where the request comes from, and to deliver the sound on the correct speaker.
Have you an idea ?

Comment: Are you using Actions on Google?

Comment: yes, i use dialogflow